# Selected Item data from a table to textbox in ZK

Tags: textbox, frameworks, zk, selecteditem

I'm developing a small web application for storing data of a hospital's patients in order to learn more about zk and it's amazing features.

My goal this time is when I select a row (checkmark) I want to take the data of the row (red color) to their corresponding textbox (blue) and this works when I choose any row of the table:

[image]

Maybe it's a kind of configuration of the listbox or maybe I have to implement a method to get what I want, I don't know.

It will be great if you give me a hand with this.

Comment: In other words, when you select a row you want to see the details? Are you working Mvc, mvvm or richlets?

Comment: i'm using mvvm, the idea is when i select a row the data also show in the textbox above (color red of the pic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's nice to see ZK is spreading and I hope you like it, I know I do like it.
Your goal is actually on the ZK demo.

https://www.zkoss.org/zkdemo/grid/data_binding

The advantage of the demo site is that you can download the code so you can modify it also.
If you don't understand the demo, post some comment with a good explication what you don't understand and I'll try to update the answer with the explication.

Comment: Awesome, i gonna read the example and if i have some questions i know that i can count with you. Thank you very much.

Comment: I solved the issue thanks to the example, i modified it in order to understand and now i got it. Thanks for your help :)