# Textbox Enabling in ZK

Tags: textbox, frameworks, zk

Continuing with my zk studies, now i have a better knowledge about data binding features from here

[Selected Item data from a table to textbox in ZK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36875530/selected-item-data-from-a-table-to-textbox-in-zk)

thanks for the previous help i resolved the issue, now i have a small request for someone that has experience using ZK and it is when i select an item from this table

http://s33.postimg.org/mo1bu0ua6/Sample.jpg

i want to enable all the component of above, the textboxes and the buttons and only when i do the selection.

How works the components restrictions enable/disable in ZK in this particular case? i am open to your suggestions, thank you for your time.

Comment: mvc or mvvm pattern?

Comment: I'm using mvvm pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you work with MVVM patter it's actually very easy :

```
<textbox value="bind(vm.selectedObject.textValue)" readonly="@load(empty vm.selectedObject)" />
```

databinding works for each attribute and you can use [some keywords](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZUML_Reference/EL_Expressions/Operators) in it.

Comment: First, thank you for your answer, but i think you don't get my question, i already know the basics about data binding, my goal now is:                           1. when i select a row of the table (please view the link of the picture) i want  to enable all the components above (textboxes and buttons)

Comment: 2. If no element of the table is selected i want to keep the components disable of editing in case of the textboxes and clicking in case of the buttons. I hope you get my question now.

Comment: I completly get your question. You hold your selected object in the vm correct? No item selected => null. Readonly is true when selected object is null. Just put that on all your components

Comment: Oh man, my apoligies, i read about the features that you showed me in your answer, you are 100% right. I'm now testing the solution. Thanks.

Comment: Last question, you told me: textboxes - readonly, buttons - disable and how about a calendar? which property let me enable/disable it?

Comment: I solved the calendar thing, it is with enabled too.

Comment: The databinding with combination of el expressions is powerfull. That's why I like to use the mvvm pattern.