# Days Calculation Method (using ZK and MVVM)

Tags: mvvm, datepicker, frameworks, zk

Well, well, step by step i'm chaining all my doubts about ZK framework and MVVM pattern on a simple series of questions, if someone is interested:

[Selected Item data from a table to textbox in ZK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36875530/selected-item-data-from-a-table-to-textbox-in-zk)

[Textbox Enabling in ZK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37649566/textbox-enabling-in-zk)

Now, with all the data correctly binded, i decided to play around with the date of my form. So the idea is when i choose a date, it calculates the days with a operation and show it in another textbox, here is the code:

.zul File

```
 <datebox id="" format="medium" onCreate="" value="@bind(vm.fechaIngreso)" width="100%" 
 onSelect="@command('calcularDias')" mold="rounded" readonly="true" constraint="no empty, no future"
 disabled="@load(empty vm.camaPaciente)"/>
```

Command on Viewmodel

```
@Command
@NotifyChange({"fechaIngreso"})
public void calcularDias(){
  long milisegundosPorDia = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  java.util.Date hoy = new Date();
  long tmp = (hoy.getTime() - this.getFechaRegistro().getTime())/milisegundosPorDia;
  this.setDiasEstancia((int)tmp);
}
```

where "hoy" = today date and getFechaRegistro = registration date, it suppose it has to calculate the number of days in another textbox, but it doesn't work. Maybe is a binding problem or a calculation problem. i appreciate any suggestion of solution to my problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I suppose your textbox is bound to the `diasEstancia` property? then
   you should let the command notify a change of that value:
   `@NotifyChange({"diasEstancia"})`
2. You don't use the property `fechaIngreso` (which is bound to your datebox)  to calculate the day difference, but you use `this.getFechaRegistro()` which is not changed as far as I see from the code posted. Therefore, the value in `diasEstancia` never changes (at one day).

Comment: Oh i see, i forgot to bind the "diasEstancia" (days as a int value) property and yeah, you're right, i declared a couple of variables related with dates and i called the wrong one, hehe and i'm looking for errors of the method and it's a binding error again. Thank you for your answer flo!